# My doctor failed Treatment; is there any way I can get bonus dice for Recovery?

Tags: burning-wheel

My character is injured. A midi wound, let's say.

I get help from a doctor who fails Treatment. I know I have to eat the consequences of that failed Treatment (losing a point from an ability, in the case of a midi wound).

When it's time to make the test for Recovery, though: can someone else treat me to grant me some bonus dice? Or am I out of luck because the first doctor screwed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out of luck. Let It Ride is in full effect. You generally want any sort of treatment as soon as possible, as it prevents the injury from bleeding into a more serious one, which threatens worse Obstacles and outcomes than from botched Treatment and Recovery.

Save artha for recovering from injuries if you plan on getting into a Fight!